# Response undefined / arrives too late - Facebook API FB.api

Tags: javascript, facebook, response

```
function getEvents(){
FB.api("/282281666473/events", function(response){
eventsList(response);
}

function eventsList(response) {
    var arr= response;
    for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
        if(!arr[i]){
            dateCheck(arr[i],i);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I configured the domain and everything, it works. 
the problem is on `var arr= response.data`

Because the response is undefined there is a error.
I have already succeed to get to a situation where the response gets the right values, but it gets those too late! Only after I'm getting to this line, and suddenly the debugger jumps to the line `FB.api("/282281666473/events", function(response){` and gives the response its value. But again, its too late because the response sent to the second function was undefined.

What can I do? Why is it undefined some times, and when its not undefined, it is  updated too late? 
Can I wait in the line `FB.api("/282281666473/events", function(response){` until the response arrives?

(I have a login button and before this call I'm logged in to facebook so I will have a token to get to the public page and get the events).

Comment: you are already using an asynchronous callback with FB.api, not sure what the problem is, to be honest...debug the response value (NOT response.data) to see if there is any error.

Comment: the code ALREADY ways for a response to come in, and doesn't call your `function(response)` until. there's no such thing as "too late". the callback you provide doesn't execute until there's something to callback with. perhaps the api call's failing and you're simply assuming it succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see is that you are missing one curly bracers and parenthesis:

```
function getEvents() {
    FB.api("/282281666473/events", function (response) {
        eventsList(response);
    }); //Missing parenthesis.
} //Missing curly bracers.
```

As per the rest, it's a callback, should be working as expected unless the fb api call fails, check your console for error responses.

Comment: good catch! that´s why it is a good idea to use a proper IDE and tools like eslint (or jslint/jshint).